# Recommend Books for Developing ASP.NET User and Custom Controls

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, controls

Please recommend books for developing ASP.NET User and Custom Controls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**ASP.NET Developer's
    Cookbook**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672325241)

Particularly following chapters

1. [**Chapter 2: User Controls**](http://aspalliance.com/cookbook/ViewChapter.aspx?Chapter=2)
2. [**Chapter 3: Custom Controls**](http://aspalliance.com/cookbook/ViewChapter.aspx?Chapter=3)

and following is better as well

[**Pro ASP.NET 3.5 Server Controls and AJAX Components**](http://apress.com/book/view/1590598652)

Comment: I was just going to mention the Pro ASP.Net/Apress book.  I've read it, very in-depth.  The entire "Pro" series is excellent for .Net and ASP.Net.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good one:

[Developing Microsoft ASP.NET Server Controls and Components](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615829).